# Is registering a marriage in Taiwan required for Taiwanese citizens living abroad?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, legal, taiwan, weddings, taiwanese-citizens

Two Canadian citizens are getting married in Canada, and one of them is also a Taiwanese citizen. The couple plan on living in Canada, but will be going to Taiwan to visit family.

Are they required to also register their marriage in Taiwan? If it's not required, are there benefits to registering the marriage?

Comment: Why is this question about registering a marriage tagged "Customs-and-Immigration" ?

Comment: I thought maybe registering a marriage might also kick-off an immigration process for the non-Taiwanese citizen in Taiwan?

Comment: I can't speak for Taiwan specifically, but generally speaking, countries recognize each other's marriages quite freely and the original marriage certificate (and maybe a translation) is all you ever need. The main exception is gay marriage, but even that's more an issue of local law than the paperwork itself.

Comment: Thanks. You're right that the existence of a marriage can be relevant to immigration, visa issuance, and allowance or refusal of entry.

Comment: What did the Taiwan embassy/consulate in Canada say when you asked them?

Comment: @Traveller Taiwan is generally not a recognized country so there is no embassy or consulate in Canada or most other countries of the world. A similar function will be filled by the "Taipei Economic and Cultural Office", of which there is one in Canada, on Yonge St. in Toronto.

Answer (score 2):

The short answers is not required because Taiwan generally will recognize the legality of  foreign marriage certificate and Canada passport holder doesn't require a VISA application to visit Taiwan in advance if you don't intent to stay/work longer in Taiwan. In any case you need to the proof used in Taiwan, you might have to contact Taiwan's consulates in Canada for "document authentication" purpose but registration in Taiwan household registry might still not required (You still can register it if you plan to get a Taiwan citizenship/passport for your child). Taiwan's registration is mainly a system to manage residency status that are not directly related to the legality of your marriage status.

Answer (score 0):

Passing citizenship to children, that is the issue.

You should get advice from the Taipei Economic and Cultural Office.
And perhaps also in Taiwan also.
Because having your marriage registered in Taiwan can be required to pass citizenship onto your children. I did see a married couple get paperwork specially notarised and taken to the office for this, and then a couple of days running around in Taiwan as well.

Military service is still required for male citizens.